# Vs-code extension error: This extension is deprecated as it is no longer being maintained

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

there are problems in this way in some extensions that I have installed.
have you seen this problem ?

When I deleted vs code and uploaded it back, nothing changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a way for the authors to explicitly tell that the extension is no longer being maintained (see this [github discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/1) about how it works).

As for the npm extension, in the Details section the authors say:

> ❗IMPORTANT: This extension has been deprecated. Support for running
> npm scripts is now provided by VS Code. You can run npm scripts as
> tasks using [task auto detection](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_task-autodetection) or from the [npm scripts explorer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_run-npm-scripts-as-tasks-from-the-explorer).

Basically it means that VSCode supports this functionality out of the box now, and there is no need for an extension to run npm stripts.

Answer (score 1):

[Issue 179756](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179756) revisit that, and complement the message with [PR 179880](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/179880)
(available today in [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) for VSCode 1.78, Apr. 2023):

> Currently, if a user has a deprecated extension installed we just render that in the Extensions view. Looking at telemetry, we noticed that users this is not a strong signal, and users still have a lot of deprecated extensions installed.
>
> Due to that, I suggest that we nudge the users more about deprecated extensions.
> Especially if the deprecated extension has an alternative.

Hence:

A deprecated extension will trigger a notification (that you will be able to dismiss with a "`Don't Show Again`").

Plus:

> Yes, there will be an action to list the deprecated extensions.

The action is "**`Show Deprecated Extensions`**".